# Printing to a text file in c using strings

Tags: c

I want the program to print the word *hello* to the text file by means of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    char word[10] = {"hello"};
    FILE*fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\temp\\Dictionary.txt", "w+"); 

    fprintf(fp, word[0]);
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem, apart from some basic syntax errors?

Comment: somehow i am usin the fprintf incorrectly because text is not being displayed to the text file.

Comment: Fully enable your compiler warnings.  It should complain about `fprintf(fp, word[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing first char instead of the string. And it might not be a valid format either. Correct call will be `fprintf(fp, "%s", word)`. And don't forget to close file too.

Comment: How can i scan a string word and put it in a string array ? I am currently using     scanf("%s", &word_entered[5]);     but it's not working. Thnks

Comment: What is type of word_entered? With the declarations from the code in the question, it should be scanf("%s", word). See examples here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ Beware though that scanf reads from std in, not from a file or other string. And scanning strings using scanf is considered dangerous as someone can type in a much longer string then your buffer can take.

Comment: Most likely scanf("%s", word_entered[5]); is what you're after. But it depends on actual type declarations.

Comment: I need the scanf to check what the user enters (word) and puts it in the array word_entered[5]

Comment: You will need to pre-allocate a buffer for each word (in one way or another) and then supply pointer to corresponding buffer in a scanf call as was already shown above. It's also not related to the original question in any way. So, if above is not helping, I'd suggest posting another question with sample code and all that comes with it.